# Jinja2 recursion over python dictionary and sets

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, jinja2, nested-loops

I'm looping over a dictionary in a jinja template that has almost an endless amount of children. the children contain sets, and dictionaries. I'm trying to loop over the following data set and print it via jinja like the example below:

```
EYE
COURSES
CLASS_0E
CLASS_0F
EYE|MIT
COURSES
CLASS_1E
CLASS_2F
EYE|MIT|NIT
COURSES
CLASS_1X
CLASS_1D
EYE|MIT|NIT|XXX
COURSES
CLASS_4X
EYE|EDX
COURSES
CLASS_9A
CLASS_9B
```

Here's the dataset working with:

```
SCHOOL = {
  'EYE': {
    'COURSES': {
      'CLASS_0E',
      'CLASS_0F'
    },
    'EYE|MIT': {
      'COURSES': {
        'CLASS_1E',
        'CLASS_2F'
      },
      'EYE|MIT|NIT': {
        'COURSES': {
          'CLASS_1X',
          'CLASS_1D'
        },
        'EYE|MIT|NIT|XXX': {
          'COURSES': {
            'CLASS_4X'
          }
        }
      },
      'EYE|EDX': {
        'COURSES': {
          'CLASS_9A',
          'CLASS_9B'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what I've done so far in an attempt to loop over it but no luck.

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template(
"""
  {% for key, value in tree.items() recursive %}
    {{key}}
  {% if key == "COURSES" %}
    COURSES
    {{loop(value.items())}}
  {% else  %}
     * GOTO INTO THE NEXT CHILD AND REPEAT THE PROCESS *
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor%}
""")

print(template.render(tree = SCHOOL))
```

How would I solve this recursive problem in Jinja2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching for some time, I figured it out.

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template("""
{%- macro recurse(n) %}
    {%- for key, value in n.items() %}
        {%- if key is not equalto 'COURSES' %}
            {{key}}
        {%- endif %}
        {%- if 'COURSES' in value and value is iterable %}
            COURSES
            {%- for item in value['COURSES'] %}
                {{item}}
            {%- endfor %}
        {%- endif %}
        {%- if value.items is defined %}
            {{recurse(value)}}
        {%- endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
{%- endmacro %}
{{ recurse(tree) }}
""")

print(template.render(tree=SCHOOL))
```

Jinja templating engine has a lot of conditionals not in python. But Jinja cares for whitespace so you would need to format the above code like this:

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template("""
{% macro recurse(n) %}{% for key, value in n.items() %}{% if key is not equalto 'COURSES' %}{{key}}{% endif %}{% if 'COURSES' in value and value is iterable %}
COURSES{% for item in value['COURSES'] %}
{{item}}{% endfor %}{% endif %}{% if value.items is defined %}   
{{recurse(value)}}{% endif%}{% endfor %}{% endmacro %}{{ recurse(tree) }}
""")

print(template.render(tree=SCHOOL))
```

which would give me the following output I needed:

```
EYE
COURSES
CLASS_0E
CLASS_0F   
EYE|MIT
COURSES
CLASS_1E
CLASS_2F   
EYE|MIT|NIT
COURSES
CLASS_1X
CLASS_1D   
EYE|MIT|NIT|XXX
COURSES
CLASS_4X   
EYE|EDX
COURSES
CLASS_9B
CLASS_9A
```